# Force an inline-block to wrap withour a br

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, containing two `<a>`.  The width of the `div` is larger than the sum of the widths of the two `<a>`.

I want the two `<a>` to wrap, but not to take all the div width.  I want them to take the width they usually take when set to display:inline-block, but to wrap like if set to display: block.

I need a css only solution.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKW4t/) to explain my example.  Thanks!

```
<div class="content">
    <a>
        <span>content1</span>
    </a>
    <a>
        <span>content2</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you might try:

```css
div{
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: auto;
}

a{
    display: block;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

Float the `a` to the left and use `clear: both`.

Apply `overflow: auto` to the parent div to retain the floats within the block.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/cKW4t/2/

I assumed that by wanting the elements to wrap, you mean each starts on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for but try moving the display:block/inline-block to .content instead of a.

Does that solve your problem?

```
div{
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}

a{
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cKW4t/1/)

Comment: This solution does not seem to work, I need both <a> to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
a {
    display: inline; 
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
a+a:before {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

I would like to add that if there is content inside you div, or if you div has a min-height, there might be a better solution.